# Оптимальный контейнер для быстого перемещения объектов

Tags: c++, c++17

Какой наиболее оптимальный контейнер подойдет для реализации следующей задачи.

Быстрое перемещение объектов в любую сторону, начало/середина/конец контейнера по принципу *Z - индексирования*.

К примеру, вызывается метод открывающий какой-то так сказать ***popup***, и этот popup объект должен переместиться в конец контейнера на некоторое время, после чего должен будет удалиться или просто перемещен на 1 позицию вниз для перекрытия контента или показа того или иного сообщения/предупреждения/ошибки.

Такие контейнеры как `map` `vector` думаю совсем не подойдут, по одной из причин, у `vector` или `map` придется дергать всю коллекцию для перемещения или свапать объекты или перемещать.

Смотрел на `list`, но тут думаю тоже есть свои свиньи.

`multi[set\map]` хорошо смотрится, но не уверен в его быстродействии.

Comment: попробуйте для начала написать это все на базе обычного vector. Ну или на базе `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`. С большой вероятностью это ровно то, что Вам нужно. А потом уже тестируйте производительность. Если у Вас объекты небольшие и кол-во элементов меньше сотни, то вектор скорее всего будет самое лучшее решение

Comment: напишите **все** операции над элементами. Пока обычное дерево вполне подходит.

Comment: А у Вас (в приведенном примере) порядок рендеринга объектов зависит от прохода по контейнеру, в котором они хранятся (т.е. чем больше индекс, тем позднее будет отрисовываться объект)?

Comment: Упоминание set/map делает вопрос непонятным. Что вы имеете в виду под "быстрым перемещением"? Быструю реорганизацию данных в памяти? Или быстрый поиск нового места для вставки?

Comment: Что-то подобное я делал через стек + мап. Мап представлял собой статичное хранилище окон с ключом = имени. Стек представлял собой иерархию открытых окон, вершина стека - текущее открытое окно. Как только надо открыть какое-то окно, то добавляем указатель/ссылку на это окно в стек. Как только окно закрывается - мы просто удаляем верхний элемент стека и отоблражаем новую вершину (если таковая имеется).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как Вам идея завести массив указателей на объекты, и при желании перемещать сами объекты - перемещать указатели на них(гораздо быстрее).Отсортированный, нужным образом, такой массив указателей на объекты, будет нужной последовательностью объектов.